# Undetectable Proxy or VPN Protocol

Tags: openvpn, wireguard

Is there a safe way for creating a proxy, tunnel, or VPN that cannot be detected by the datacenter or ISPs?

I'm living in an oppressing country, but I've access to a VPS with less regulated access to the Internet. I was hoping to find a secure protocol for tunneling my traffic through that VPS without them knowing?

Speed limits and traffic reshaping (like connecting and disconnecting it to look like web browsing burst traffic) are not an issue. I'm just looking for a protocol that can be easily and quickly set up.

I've heard that OpenVPN does not limit the ports that can be used, but I'm not sure if that's enough. I've also heard that WireGaurd has built-in tools for reshaping the traffic.

Comment: VPN traffic can always be detected. It's all a matter of how difficult it is to detect. If the ISP knows what to look for, it will detect it.

Comment: @schroeder I don't think they're actively looking for it, but rather, have automatic tests that check for the basic properties of such connections.

Comment: Then what will be detectable depends on how the detection is configured. That's still an "active" looking.